# OpenCvSharp, attempt to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, opencv

Hello to everyone this is my first question.

I'm developing a software with OpenCvSharp, obviously, in c#, the goal of this software is apply a median blur filter to a bitmap working through memory.

Code example:

```
        using (Bitmap bmpSrc = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\IPTE40\Desktop\OpenCV\View2.bmp"))
        {
            unsafe
            {
                BitmapData bmpDataSrc = bmpSrc.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpSrc.Width, bmpSrc.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmpSrc.PixelFormat);

                int iNumberOfBytesOriginal = bmpDataSrc.Stride * bmpSrc.Height;
                byte[] byteArrayOriginal = new byte[iNumberOfBytesOriginal];
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bmpDataSrc.Scan0, byteArrayOriginal, 0, iNumberOfBytesOriginal);
                IntPtr ptrDataSrc = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(byteArrayOriginal, 0);

                Mat matImgSrc = new Mat(ptrDataSrc);
                Mat matImgDst = new Mat();
                Cv2.MedianBlur(matImgSrc, matImgDst, 9);
                matImgDst.SaveImage(@"C:\Users\IPTE40\Desktop\OpenCV\View2_median_blur.bmp");

                matImgSrc.Dispose();
                matImgDst.Dispose();

                bmpSrc.UnlockBits(bmpDataSrc);
            }
        }
```

In the line `Cv2.MedianBlur(matImgSrc, matImgDst, 9);` I get the error (Attempt to read or write protected memory)

Please, someone can help me?

Thank you and regards.

Comment: Why are you copying memory? You should be able to pass `Scan0` directly into your `Medianblur` function without using the `UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement` method. What happens if you do that?

Comment: With this:

`Mat matImgSrc = new Mat(bmpDataSrc.Scan0);`
`Cv2.MedianBlur(matImgSrc, matImgDst, 9);`

The same error.

Comment: Try changing `ImageLockMode.ReadOnly` to `ImageLockMode.ReadWrite`.